# Разяснить о async awite

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

Есть 2 функции - одна обращяется к файлу и возвращяет данные, после их образет и возвращяет в переменную эту переменую подхватывает другая функция и выводит в консоле. Используя **async awite** так как в пример я получаю **undefined**. Через классический  **new Promise & then** все работает, подскажите что не так с **async awite** ?

```
const readFile = (file) => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function(err, data){
        if(err) console.log(err)
        console.log(data.length)
        const s = data.slice(0, 30)
        return s
    })
}

const getName = (string) => {
    console.log(`this is 0-30 string in data ->${string}`)
}


async function asyncFunction(){
    const st = await readFile('./src/resources/source_data/foo.html')
    await getName(st)
}

asyncFunction()
```

Comment: `readFile()` синхронная блокирующая функция, на сколько мне известно

Comment: readFile() у тебя синхронная, попробуй ее тоже сделать с async. Ты ведь должен вернуть промис с нее.

Comment: Спасибо, Глупейшая ошибка )))

Answer (score 1):

`const r = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')` **Асинхронные** функции в помощь!
*Ошибка новичка*